# Save Layer Output in Keras Custom Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, shapes, layer

I'm building a custom layer in Keras that's supposed to remember its previous output.

The layer itself has a few nested layers (conv2 -> norm -> relu) that are executed in order.
I was thinking of using tf.Variable to store my results but ran into issues due to variable batch sizes.

The idea is to:

- Get layer input
- Concatenate previous output stored in a variable (initially zero in the first run)
- Run it through the nested layers conv2 -> norm -> relu
- Save the output of relu to the variable (tf.keras.backend.update)

How can I circumvent the problem of variable batch sizes? They prevent me from initializing a Variable with all zeros in build().

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
class OnePassRecurrent(keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, output_size, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        super(OnePassRecurrent, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(self.output_size, self.kernel_size, padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal') # Notice no activation. Added after layer norm
        self.norm1 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.relu1 = layers.ReLU()
        
        output_shape = input_shape.as_list()
        output_shape[-1] = self.output_size

        # TODO This does not work right now
        #self.last_output = tf.Variable(tf.fill(input_shape, 0.0), validate_shape=False, trainable=False)
        #self.last_output = tf.Variable(tf.fill(tf.TensorShape(input_shape), 0.0))
                
    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        lastx = self.last_output
        x = layers.Concatenate()([inputs, lastx])
            
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.norm1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        
        tf.keras.backend.update(self.last_output, x)
        
        return x
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Tf.variable is a part of computation graph and its shape should probably be fixed. I would try to create tf.variable of maximum size and use paddings

Comment: Why do you need cache layer output in itself ? How do you reuse this output ?

Comment: `They prevent me from initializing a Variable with all zeros in build().` Can you be more precise? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @Mithril I'm trying to re-use the previous run's output in the next run of the training. Kind of like an RNN but with only 1 timestep as the input to the network with the second timestep coming from the previous run.

Comment: @Lescurel I ment this line 
```self.last_output = tf.Variable(tf.fill(input_shape, 0.0), validate_shape=False, trainable=False)```
I have also tried tf.zeros and tf.zeros_like with the same result. All I get is that I can't create a Tensor with partially known shape.

Comment: You make me confused .  What you say looks like just use one input  pass down many layers(every layer output as input to next , just need a for loop)  .  If  it is resnet , one layer use previous output and intput concatenated . But you wrote `Get layer input(previous output)  Concatenate previous output ` in question ,  hard to understand .

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't mean to pass on the output to the next layer. I'm talking about saving 'old' outputs and using them over time like a recurrent network. So each layer will remember it's output and use it for itself in the next timestep. Does this make sense?